# Amazon Aurora Serverless (MySQL): How to encrypt jdbc connection?

Tags: mysql, encryption, jdbc, aws-aurora-serverless

I want to use a Amazon Aurora Serverless with my spring boot applications. I need to encrypt the jdbc connection between my application and Aurora, unfortunately I didn’t find any documentation according this topic.

Have anybody any experience with this topic?
How can i encrypt jdbc connection?

Comment: You shall use ssl as with any connection with mysql. Can you use the *requireSSL* and *verifyServerCertificate* with the connection [properties](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Serverless cluster should already have the cert installed on it. You shouldn't need anything specific to talk TLS with the endpoint.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html#aurora-serverless.tls

You can use additional client side settings and enforce the mode of SSL verification as well. (Details in the doc link above)